# How do I run a cron job in my eventstore image?

Tags: docker, cron

I am trying to run a cron job in my Docker image.  When I use this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install cron

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/simple-cron

# Add shell script and grant execution rights
ADD script.sh /script.sh
RUN chmod +x /script.sh

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/simple-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

then it works fine.  If I change the `FROM` to 
`FROM eventstore/eventstore`, then my cronjob stops working.  The `eventstore` is based on `ubuntu:1604`, so it seems that it should continue to work.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption:** you want to run cron in background while running eventstore.

**Things to know:**
In dockerfile, "CMD" section gets appended to "ENTRYPOINT" section as arguments. For example

```
ENTRYPOINT ["echo","running entrypoint"]
CMD ["echo","runnning cmd"]
```

will result in following output

```
running entrypoint echo running cmd
```

**Explanation of your issue:**
In your Dockerfile, cron is executed as CMD, which works fine when your parent image is ubuntu:latest as it does not have any ENTRYPOINT defined. Whereas eventstore/eventstore has ENTRYPOINT defined which results in executing following

```
/entrypoint.sh cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

which could also result in unexpected behaviour of eventstore itself depending on how entrypoint.sh is defined. At best it will ignore any arguments.

**Solution:**
define a script "custom-entrypoint.sh" to run cron followed by eventstore entrypoint script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cron && /entrypoint.sh
```

and then define your Dockerfile to add custom-entrypoint.sh and run it as
ENTRYPOINT. final Dockerfile should look something like

```
FROM eventstore/eventstore

# Install cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install cron

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/simple-cron

# Add shell script and grant execution rights
ADD script.sh /script.sh
RUN chmod +x /script.sh

# Add custom entrypoint shell script
ADD custom-entrypoint.sh /custom-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /custom-entrypoint.sh

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/simple-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
ENTRYPOINT ["/custom-entrypoint.sh"]
```